# How do I diplay an icon on a JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Tags: java, swing, icons, joptionpane

I have the following code:

```
 principleInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the   principle.","Find Interest Rate", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

I want to display an icon in the JOptionPane as well as my message. How do I do that?
I get an error message when I do this:

```
final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://iconizer.net/files/Devine_icons/thumb/128/Calculater.png"));
 principleInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the   principle.","Find Interest Rate", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,icon);
```

Comment: Maybe try the method that takes an `Icon` as a parameter? `showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType, Icon icon, Object[] selectionValues, Object initialSelectionValue)`

Comment: That is for a dropdown list, not a text field.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here. Also post the full stack trace of your error and mentioned the relevant line numbers in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an image to an `JOptionPane` I believe this is what you  are after

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("yourimage.imagetype");
        Image image2 = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(200,200,0);
        String principleInputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the   principle.","Find Interest Rate", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(image2),  null, "").toString();
    }
}
```

For more information look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-)